# Are Differential equations without "$x$" considered separable?

Tags: differential

For example:
Do we consider all differential equations of the form $y'(x)=f(y)$ separable?
why/why not?

Answer (score 0):

It would be separable. Check if $f(y) = 0$ is a solution. Then ignore this case to get
$$\frac{y'}{f(y)} = 1 $$
so your solution looks like
$$\int\frac{y'}{f(y)} = x + C $$

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting what you have written as:

$$y'(x)=f(y(x))$$

Separable equations can be written in the form:

$$A(y(x))y'(x) = B(x)$$

So if you choose $A(y) = \frac{1}{f(y)}$ and $B(x) = 1$. $f(y)$ should not equal zero on your interval of analysis in order for you to be able to make this transformation.